# How to make a Bash function that will source the virtual environment in the current folder?

Tags: python, bash

I'm sure that this is a simple matter but I have looked and I couldn't find out how to do it.

I have a naming convention with my Python virtual environments of calling it `venv_xyz`. With `xyz` being the name of the current project. To activate the virtual environment, I would then need to type this command:

`source venv_xyz/bin/activate`.

Every part of that stays the same, except for the `xyz` aspect. And I only ever have one virtual environment in a the directory that I'm working in.

I'd like to write an alias/function to automate this, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried the function below, but I still need to type the name `venv_xyz` to make it work.

```
setvenv() {
    source $1/bin/activate
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to do it. Use globbing (file path expansion). This is what worked:

`alias sop='source venv*/bin/activate/'`